# no images are displayed on the phone instead of the button (android)

Tags: python, kivy

I'm trying to add an image via *background_normal* instead of the text on the button. When I run the code on the computer, the image is displayed correctly. When I create an apk file for android and run it on my phone, I have white squares instead of buttons with a picture. Why is that? Or how can I fix it? Below is an example of the code. And in the **bulldozer.spec** file, I commented out the *source.include_exts* line

```
class Application(App):
    def build(self):

        self.recv_stream, self.send_stream=None,None

        Layout=BoxLayout(orientation='vertical',spacing=20,padding=(0,20))
        self.Haut_Layout=GridLayout(cols=2, size_hint=(0.4,0.2),pos_hint={'x':.1, 'y':.1})
        self.orientation='veritcal' 

        Layout.add_widget(self.Haut_Layout)
        
        self.BoutonConnect=Button(text='Connection')
        self.BoutonConnect.bind(on_press=self.connect)

        self.Haut_Layout.add_widget(self.BoutonConnect)
                
        self.BoutonConnect1=Button(text='Line')
        self.BoutonConnect1.size_hint=(0.6, 0.2)
        self.BoutonConnect1.pos_hint={'x':.5, 'y':.5}
        self.BoutonConnect1.bind(on_press=self.send)
        self.BoutonConnect1.id='6'

        self.Haut_Layout.add_widget(self.BoutonConnect1)
        
        self.Bas_Layout=GridLayout(cols=3, spacing=10, size_hint=(0.9, 0.9),pos_hint={'x':.05, 'y':.1})

        Layout.add_widget(self.Bas_Layout)
        
        self.Bouton1=Button()
        self.Bouton1.background_color=[0,0,0,0]

        self.Bas_Layout.add_widget(self.Bouton1)

        self.Bouton2=Button()

        self.Bouton2.background_normal="go1.png"
        self.Bouton2.background_down="go.png"
        
        self.Bouton2.bind(on_press=self.send)
        self.Bouton2.id='1'

        self.Bas_Layout.add_widget(self.Bouton2)
        
        self.Bouton3=Button()

        self.Bouton3.background_normal="stop1.png"
        self.Bouton3.background_down="stop.png"
        self.Bouton3.bind(on_press=self.send)
        self.Bouton3.id='3'
        self.Bas_Layout.add_widget(self.Bouton3)
        
        self.Bouton4=Button()

        self.Bouton4.background_normal="left1.png"
        self.Bouton4.background_down="left.png"
        self.Bouton4.bind(on_press=self.send)
        self.Bouton4.id='4'

        self.Bas_Layout.add_widget(self.Bouton4)

        self.Bouton5=Button()
 
        self.Bouton5.background_normal="back1.png"
        self.Bouton5.background_down="back.png"
        self.Bouton5.bind(on_press=self.send)
        self.Bouton5.id='2'

        self.Bas_Layout.add_widget(self.Bouton5)
        
        self.Bouton6=Button()

        self.Bouton6.background_normal="rigth1.png"
        self.Bouton6.background_down="rigth.png"
        self.Bouton6.bind(on_press=self.send)
        self.Bouton6.id='5'
        
        self.Bas_Layout.add_widget(self.Bouton6)
        
        return Layout
```

Comment: it may run code from different folder then you expect and it may not find images - it may need to use `/full/path/to/images` or use some method to get `/full/path/to/folder/with/code` and always add it to image name.

Comment: @furas I used /full/path/to/images. unfortunately, it didn't help me. Can you tell me which method you need to use to get /full/path/to/folder/with/code?

Comment: first: can you find your image on Android using  any file explorer/manager? If image doesn't exist on Android then you can't access it. Full path to folder with code is `BASE = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))` - at least it works on Linux/Windows/Mac. You may also use this path with `os.listdir(BASE)` to see all files in this folder - to check if image is available in this folder.